# disabled NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem

I programmatically create an NSMenuItem and it is disabled. If I override the validateMenuItem: method and return YES for all items, the menu item works fine.

Why would it not be enabled when I tell the menu to autoEnableItems and dont override the validateMenuItem: method?

```
NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:label action:@selector(methodToLogSomething:) keyEquivalent:@""];
menuItem.representedObject = representedObject;
[menuItem setTarget:self];
[menu insertItem:menuItem atIndex:[[menu itemArray] count]-1];
[menuItem release];
[menu setAutoenablesItems:YES];
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It appears that menu items stay disabled if their target and action are not setup properly. In my case, I forgot the `:` at the end of my selector.

Comment: I forgot to set the Target via `setTarget`. Not setup properly as well. Thanks!

Comment: This answer also helps if you are trying to disable for certain menu items

Comment: Spent several hours trying to figure this out, thanks folks!